# vuejs2 mousehover on routerlink tag li fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have the following links

```
     <router-link v-for="(setting, key) in settings"
                  :key="key" class="has-sub-menu"
                    tag="li" :to="setting.to"
                    @mouseover="linkHover(true)" @mouseleave="linkHover(false)"
                    >
                  <router-link
                          :to="setting.to">
                      <div class="icon-w">
                          <div :class="setting.icon"></div>
                      </div>
                      <span >{{setting.name}}</span> //here it works
                  </router-link>
                  <div class="children">
                        ///here children stuff
                   <div>

        </router-link>
```

the above generates a html

```
<li><a href="">my link</a></li>
```

and in my scripts

```
data:()=>({
    settings:[
     {name:'Home',to:'/', children:[{name:'test2'}]}
      //other routes here
    ]
 })
 methods:{
   linkHover(val){
    console.log("test",val)
   }    

 }
```

The above hover fails to log to the console
But when i transfer the mouse hover to

```
<span @mouseover="linkHover(true)">
```

it works

How do i make it work on the li element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VueJS 2.x event listeners on components (e.g. router-link) only listen to custom events. If you need to listen to the native event on a component you need to use the `native` modifier

```
<router-link v-for="(setting, key) in settings"
                  :key="key" class="has-sub-menu"
                    tag="li" :to="setting.to"
                    @mouseover.native="linkHover(true)" @mouseleave.native="linkHover(false)"
                    >
....
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components